# PHP PDO query works without parameters but not with

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very simple query that works when I don't use parameters. With parameters, it returns nothing. Someone else posted the same issue over here:
[Query with input parameters doesn't work whereas direct query works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502830/query-with-input-parameters-doesnt-work-whereas-direct-query-works#_=_)

However no one has answered it. Below is my code.

```
require_once('database.class.php');

class Plan extends Database {
    public function getBenefitAmounts($plan_id, $group_id, $level) {
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT benefit FROM rates WHERE plan_id = :plan AND group_id IS NULL AND `level` = :lvl';
        $params = array(':plan'=>896, ':lvl'=>1);
        $this->sqlQuery($sql, $params);

        // $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT benefit FROM rates WHERE plan_id = 896 AND group_id IS NULL AND `level` = 1';
        // $this->sqlQuery($sql);

        $results = $this->sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        $options = '';
        foreach ($results as $value) {
            $options .= '<option value="' . $value . '">$' . $value . '</option>';
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

In the database class:

```
public function sqlQuery($sql, $values_to_bind=null) {

    $this->sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    if (isset($values_to_bind)) {
        foreach ($values_to_bind as $param => $value) {
            $this->sth->bindValue($param, $value);
        }
    }
    $success = $this->sth->execute();
    if (!$success) {
        $arr = $this->$sth->errorInfo();
        print_r($arr);
    }
}
```

The code commented out of the first code snippet works just fine, but with parameters, it returns nothing. The `getBenefitAmounts` function is called from another PHP file which is called using a JQuery get.

Comment: Could it be something to do with binding a string value (the third param, defaults to string) to an integer column? Just a thought.

Comment: Did you try executing this particular statement in the database to see if it returns something?

Comment: What is return direct query to db: `SELECT DISTINCT benefit FROM rates WHERE plan_id = 896 AND group_id IS NULL AND level = 1;` ?

Comment: When I run the query from phpMyAdmin it returns the expected list of numbers. This is a new project. So just 5 random numbers right now as I don't have any real values to populate the system with.

Comment: when using `bindValue` `PDO` expects a value not a variable and vice versa try using `bindParam` at the place of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add the third param which is optional for bindValue(). It can be something like PDO::PARAM_INT, PDO::PARAM_STR etc. Just try to debug and see if it helps.

Comment: This solved the problem, but I've been using the same setup for almost 2 years without doing this. Any idea why this is just now becoming an issue?

Comment: Great to hear it worked. I think it defaults to  PDO::PARAM_STR so it would work if the data type of the table column is of type string which might be in most of the cases, so it might go unnoticed. 

Also try to put ':paramstring' around a string and nothing when it is integer :paramint in your $sql and see if it does things differently.

Also the problem seems that php does not complain when you don't add the third param and it might be actually doing things differently then expected. So its hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you like so much `try...catch` if you use with no sense code. Because this technique: `} catch (PDOException $e) { throw new PDOException($e);}` means the same as `} catch (PDOException $e) {;}` like you ask php to do nothing if catch. Why do you asked to catch if you do nothing in case it happens?

Now my guess about how to fix your code:

```
public function sqlQuery($sql, $values_to_bind=null) {
    $this->sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

    if (isset($values_to_bind)) {
        foreach ($values_to_bind as $param => $value) {
            $this->sth->bindValue($param, $value);
        }
    }
    $success  = $this->sth->execute();
    if (!$success) {
        $arr = $this->$sth->errorInfo();
        print_r($arr);
    }

}
```

By the way you use `$this->sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);` that means your `sqlQuery` function is a method of some class that you didn't show to us. and your first piece of code is somewhere outside that class? it would be better if you post full version of code, not just lines you think are involved.

and here you can switch to regular way:

```
    //$results = $this->sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); //you don't need it

    $options = '';
    while ($row  = $this->sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $options .= '<option value="' . $row['benefit'] . '">$' . $row['benefit'] . '</option>';
    }
```

Comment: I just inherited this code. So not sure why those tries were used, but I switched it to your code and got the same result.

Comment: None. I also updated the post with a little more detail if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Why not bind the parameters using bindParam?

```
$plan = 896;
$lvl = 1;

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT benefit FROM rates WHERE plan_id = :plan AND group_id IS NULL AND `level` = :lvl");
$sth->bindParam(":plan", $plan);
$sth->bindParam(":lvl", $lvl);
$sth->execute();
$r = $sth->fetchAll();
```